# How do you solve a logarithmic functions of the form $f(x) = \log_b (x+c) +d$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms

$f(x) = \log_b (x+c) +d$

$x-\text{intercept:} \space 2$
$y-\text{intercept:} \space 1$

contains the point $(-1,2)$
asymptotic$: x = -2$

behavior: decreasing.

This question was given to us without being taught on how to do it. What method should be used?

Comment: If you learned about linear transformations (e.g. g(x) = af(b(x-c))+d, and logarithms/exponents, then you should have enough information to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean finding the values of $ b,c, d $ .

*x-intercept: 2* means $\log_b (2+c) + d  = 0$

*y-intercept: 1* means $1 = \log_b c + d $

*contains the point* $ (-1,2) $ means  $ 2= \log_b (-1 +c) + d $

*decreasing behavior* means $ f'(x) \le 0 $

Can you go on?

Comment: So how can i get the logarithmic function with values from that?

Comment: @Anton : How would you solve $\log_{10}(c) +1 = 2$ for c?

Answer (score 0):

$1=\log_b(c)-\log_b(2+c)=\log_b(\frac{c}{2+c})$
So $b^1=b=\frac{c}{2+c}$
$\log_b(x-c)\to\infty$ as $x \to c$ .  And as $x\to-2$, $x\to+\infty$.  Therefore $c=2$.  $b$ and $d$ are easy to evaluate with $c=2$